# Tables inside tables in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database-design, geolocation

I have set up a MySQL database for location tracking on several devices. Currently, I plan to have each device having their own table in which to store their locations at various times. I was thinking that in a device's table, there would be a timestamp table which would hold latitude, longitude, and other identifying information. This is my first time using MySQL, so I'm sure this isn't the best way to do it...but is this possible? If not, what are some other alternatives?

Comment: Instead of thinking in Hierarchies (which are generally better suited to other data models), the alternative is to think in Sets and Relationships between them: there are the underlying principles of SQL Relational Databases (which are in turn based on Relational Algebra). Any number of database introduction books can explain basic table design and normalization.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see, your database schema should look more or less like this:

```
create table devices (
    id int not null auto_increment primary key,
    name ...,
    ...
) engine=INNODB;

create table device_locations (
    id int not null auto_increment primary key,
    device_id not null,
    lat ...,
    lng ...,
    ...,
    index ix_device_id(device_id),
    foreign key (device_id) references devices(id) 
) engine=INNODB;
```

What you want to do is perfectly suitable for a relational database (such as MySQL, hey it even has [built-in datatypes just for storing GIS data](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/spatial-extensions.html)), however you should probably read up on [normal forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Normal_forms) first.

Answer (score 0):

Try NoSQL databases that doesn't restrict schemas. MongoDB comes in mind when you want to structure nested collection.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm stuck with the MySQL database (at least for the time being). Are there any alternative designs I can use with what I have, still keeping track of the match between the user, time, and location?

Comment: MySQL can do it: I know of someone who has developed an entreprise application level tracing and tracking solution using MySQL as RDMS. I suggest you to do google search for similar opensource project.

Answer (score 0):

With according to Flickr experience with MySQL, it can be used as schema-less as well, just start keep serialized data in a column if you know what you want.

MySQL is primarily production-ready solution with ready-to-use tools to backup, recover, replication and sharding tool which is ideal to maintenance. If you don't want to use schema, just don't use it

Comment: You can burn a pig many ways. Most of them are not enjoyable to eat.